# How to rollback uncommitted changes to a Synapse Notebook?

Tags: azure, azure-notebooks

I have made changes directly to the backing github repo *json* notebook structure that mirror what has been done in the online notebook. To verify the repo changes I would like to revert the online changes that have not yet been committed:

[image]

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A co-worker pointed out that there is a "refresh" circle on the far upper right. I did not see it before being shown.

[image]

Upon clicking we have the choice to refresh or not:

[image]

Clicking on "Refrsh" does the trick.